# Media isn't displayed in the gallery or sound player, but are in My Files

Tags: media-files

I just woke up this morning and my photos and music weren't displayed in their respective apps. I can find everything still there on my phone under My Files and can view / play them. When i take a new photo it shows up in my gallery, but other than that the gallery is completely empty.

Can anyone help me solve this? I have a Galaxy S4

Comment: Have you installed any new apps lately?  Any 3rd party picture apps?  Any OS updates?

Comment: Actually thinking back, I installed an app to hide files

Comment: Still i'm not sure how to resolve this issue

Comment: Have you uninstalled that app to see if it resolved the issue? It could be that the app is hiding files to that your media and music apps cannot see the files. No harm in giving it a try

Comment: I've uninstalled it, restarted my phone, taken out the battery etc. Nothing has worked so far

Comment: When viewing the folders on my PC, it says the folders have 0 files and 0 bytes.

Comment: I have the same issue and I was messing around with a lot of things and don't know which thing did it :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Images have disappeared from gallery, but still in "My Files" (Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, 5.0.2)](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109833/images-have-disappeared-from-gallery-but-still-in-my-files-samsung-galaxy-s6)