# Why did a .nomedia file get added to my device? Showing 0 Image, Audio or Video Files?

Tags: gallery, files

I woke up today and my Gallery was showing 0 Image, Video or Audio files. After seeing this thread [Images have disappeared from gallery, but still in "My Files" (Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, 5.0.2)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109833/images-have-disappeared-from-gallery-but-still-in-my-files-samsung-galaxy-s6) , I plugged in my device to a laptop and deleted a .nomedia file in the root folder of my device. I deleted this file, which fixed the issue and the device rescanned everything automatically and showed all of my files.

My question is why did this file get added to my device? And if I had been unable to access a laptop how do I delete a .nomedia file from within android?

Comment: It is just a thought but I don't think problem actually originated from the file itself. But the act of deleting the file triggered the rescanning, which led to solution.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me, sorry. Surely the .nomedia file being added to root caused the problem, thus removing it fixed the problem?

Comment: I can't say my idea is 100% correct but *Surely the .nomedia file being added to root caused the problem, thus removing it fixed the problem?* is a wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the file got created by some app on your device.

You can delete the file by using any file explorer. In the **My Files** app on Samsung devices you first need to go to its settings, and enable 'Show Hidden Files'. Then the file is visible and you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The .nomedia files are made by apps like snapchat.
Most android file managers ignore these apps.

Comment: Yeah but Snapchat creates them in its own data files.